# Difficulties on mocking a jdbc Datasource

Tags: java, mocking, easymock, powermock

I want to mock a Datasource and the InitialContext to get connected to the database outside the container. This is the logic that I want to use the mock for:

```
        Connection con = null;
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/chu");
        con = datasource.getConnection();
```

This is how I proceeded

```
        // create the Connection
        connection = createMyConnection();//connection i construct manually 
        // Mock the Datasource
        DataSource datasourceMock = EasyMock.createMock(DataSource.class);
        EasyMock.expect(datasourceMock.getConnection())
                                      .andReturn(connection).anyTimes();
        // Mock the context
        Context contextMock = EasyMock.createMock(InitialContext.class);
        EasyMock.expect((DataSource)contextMock.lookup("jdbc/chu"))
                                     .andReturn(datasourceMock)
                                     .anyTimes();
PowerMock.expectNew(InitialContext.class).andReturn((InitialContext)contextMock);


        // run the mock
        PowerMock.replayAll();
```

**Problem:** the mock does not work for the DataSource it's always null,however the Mock of the InitialContext is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `PowerMock.createMock` instead of `EasyMock.createMock` if you want `PowerMock.replayAll` to work.